# Weird error while making a discord bot. How do I get this thing to run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I try to run my discord bot, i get this error in the powershell.

```
C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\WHA Period Bot\index.js:1
��c


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I've checked line one and nothing seems out of the ordinary. Here is the first 20 lines of my bot.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new discord.Client();

var date = new Date();

const token = 'REDACTED';

const prefix = '//';

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot on.');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    let announcementChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('REDACTED');

    var day = date.getDay();
    var timeHour = date.getHours();
    var timeMinutes = date.getMinutes();
```

I don't know what is going on. I would just like to get to running my bot. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use yarn? I found a *very* similar problem to yours on the web that occurred only after updating to yarn 2

Comment: No. I don't use Yarn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks a bit like a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) . That is a binary marker describing the exact flavor of Unicode that was used for encoding the file. It's several bytes at the beginning of the file, it would look like garbage to a javascript interpreter. If your text editor added this, it would be invisible in that editor.

Try taking a look at your file in a hex viewer or a different editor. Can you see any weird stuff at the beginning of the file?

For programming you should use an editor that does not add this marker.

Comment: I have opened the file in different editors and I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-bom-any-textxml-file would this help?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AlexShad, if this did answer your question, please consider accepting the answer so that others can more easily see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in your code, maybe it is your editor adding some weird stuff to the beginning of the file that you can't really see in the editor. I don't know what editor you are using, but I highly recommend Microsoft Visual Studio as it works perfectly for me. Maybe try to install it and open the code in there and see.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code but I will look into a different editor such as atom or sublime but I am not really that comfortable with switching.